# AWS BeanstalkL ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - No Application Version named?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cmd, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a scalable wordpress site via Amazon beanstalk but I am getting an issue when I try to deploy. I had originally made one environment but terminated and made a new one, now I am having deployment issues whereas before things deployed but my public IP was not working.

Below is what I get when I run the eb --debug command.

```
C:\Projects\SwagBox\wordpress>eb --debug 2018-06-23 06:06:54,671 (DEBUG) cement.core.foundation : laying cement for the 'eb' application 2018-06-23 06:06:54,671 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'pre_setup' 2018-06-23 06:06:54,671 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'post_setup' 2018-06-23 06:06:54,672 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'pre_run' 2018-06-23 06:06:54,672 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'post_run' 2018-06-23 06:06:54,672 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'pre_argument_parsing' 2018-06-23 06:06:54,672 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'post_argument_parsing' 2018-06-23 06:06:54,672 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'pre_close' 2018-06-23 06:06:54,672 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'post_close' 2018-06-23 06:06:54,672 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'signal' 2018-06-23 06:06:54,672 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'pre_render' 2018-06-23 06:06:54,672 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : defining hook 'post_render' 2018-06-23 06:06:54,672 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : registering hook 'add_handler_override_options' from cement.core.foundation into hooks['post_setup'] 2018-06-23 06:06:54,673 (DEBUG) cement.core.hook : registering hook 'handler_override' from cement.core.foundation into hooks['post_argument_parsing'] 2018-06-23 06:06:54,673 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'extension' (IExtension) 2018-06-23 06:06:54,673 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'log' (ILog) 2018-06-23 06:06:54,673 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'config' (IConfig) 2018-06-23 06:06:54,673 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'mail' (IMail) 2018-06-23 06:06:54,673 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'plugin' (IPlugin) 2018-06-23 06:06:54,673 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'output' (IOutput) 2018-06-23 06:06:54,673 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'argument' (IArgument) 2018-06-23 06:06:54,673 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'controller' (IController) 2018-06-23 06:06:54,674 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : defining handler type 'cache' (ICache) 2018-06-23 06:06:54,675 (DEBUG) cement.core.handler : registering handler '<class 'cement.core.extension.CementExtensionHandler'>' into handlers['extension']['cement'] 2018-06-23 06:06:54,675 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: C:\Projects\SwagBox\wordpress 2018-06-23 06:06:54,680 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: C:\Projects\SwagBox\wordpress 2018-06-23 06:06:54,688 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: C:\Projects\SwagBox\wordpress 2018-06-23 06:06:54,717 (DEBUG) cement.ext.ext_plugin : plugin config dir C:\etc\eb\plugins.d does not exist. 2018-06-23 06:06:54,718 (DEBUG) cement.ext.ext_plugin : plugin config dir C:\Users\saly\.eb\plugins.d does not exist. 2018-06-23 06:06:54,727 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.hooks : -- EBCLI Version: 3.14.1 2018-06-23 06:06:54,727 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.hooks : -- Python Version:
3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] 2018-06-23 06:06:54,727 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: C:\Projects\SwagBox\wordpress 2018-06-23 06:06:54,743 (DEBUG) ebcli.objects.sourcecontrol : Getting current branch name by performing `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` 2018-06-23 06:06:54,804 (DEBUG) ebcli.objects.sourcecontrol : master 2018-06-23 06:06:54,804 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: C:\Projects\SwagBox\wordpress 2018-06-23 06:06:54,822 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: C:\Projects\SwagBox\wordpress 2018-06-23 06:06:54,833 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: C:\Projects\SwagBox\wordpress 2018-06-23 06:06:54,840 (DEBUG) ebcli.objects.sourcecontrol : Getting current branch name by performing `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` 2018-06-23 06:06:54,889 (DEBUG) ebcli.objects.sourcecontrol : master 2018-06-23 06:06:54,889 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: C:\Projects\SwagBox\wordpress 2018-06-23 06:06:54,903 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: C:\Projects\SwagBox\wordpress 2018-06-23 06:06:54,912 (DEBUG) ebcli.core.fileoperations : Project root found at: C:\Projects\SwagBox\wordpress usage: eb (sub-commands ...) [options ...] {arguments ...}

Welcome to the Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Interface (EB CLI). For more information on a specific command, type "eb {cmd} --help".

commands:   abort        Cancels an environment update or deployment.  appversion   Listing and managing application versions   clone        Clones an environment.   codesource   Configures the code source for the EB CLI to use by default.   config       Modify an environment's configuration. Use subcommands to manage saved configurations.   console      Opens the environment in the AWS Elastic Beanstalk Management Console.   create       Creates a new environment.   deploy Deploys your source code to the environment.   events       Gets recent events.   health       Shows detailed environment health.   init         Initializes your directory with the EB CLI. Creates the application.   labs         Extra experimental commands.   list        Lists all environments.   local        Runs commands on your local machine.   logs         Gets recent logs.   open         Opens the application URL in a browser.   platform     Commands for managing platforms.   printenv     Shows the environment variables.   restore   Restores a terminated environment.   scale        Changes the number of running instances.   setenv       Sets environment variables.   ssh Opens the SSH client to connect to an instance.   status       Gets environment information and status.   swap         Swaps two environment CNAMEs with each other.   tags         Allows adding, deleting, updating, and listing of environment tags.   terminate    Terminates the environment.   upgrade      Updates the environment to the most recent platform version.   use          Sets default environment.

optional arguments:   -h, --help            show this help message and exit   --debug               toggle debug output   --quiet             suppress all output   -v, --verbose         toggle verbose output  
--profile PROFILE     use a specific profile from your credential file   -r REGION, --region REGION
                        use a specific region   --no-verify-ssl       do not verify AWS SSL certificates   --version             show application/version info

To get started type "eb init". Then type "eb create" and "eb open"
```

The actual error I get is:

```
Creating application version archive "app-3422-180623_061101".
Uploading: [##################################################] 100% Done...
ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - No Application Version named 'app-3422-180623_061101' found.
```

Were the application version changes each time.

I have looked online for a solution but I am still a novice and have not been able to figure it out.

I also ran

> eb config

and checked that my env name and app name where correct. I also chose the correct zone when first connecting via IAM on AWS.

Thanks again! I really appreciate it :)

Edit: typos

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay I managed to get the deployent to work and it matches up under versions in the beanstalk dashboard.

I went into the folder where I initially initiated git and deleted the .beanstalk folder. This prompted me to configure everything again and I chose the correct application name this time, which worked.

Thanks!

Comment: also for anyone stumbling on this question, running eb init --interactive works as well.

Answer (score 5):

`eb init` or `eb create` will create a folder called `.elasticbeanstalk` where it writes a config.yml file. For docker based environments, this config.yml is often incorrectly generated when you are deploying from a non-master branch.

Check that the `environment` and `application_name` values are correct. I had to update those manually for it to deploy.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same error. later, i got to know i that i was on wrong directory path, so check it once.

`.elasticbeanstalk` folder has to be in the current directory

Comment: What do you mean to be in the current directory?

Comment: `pwd`  print(present) working directory @mrRobot