# AWS Beanstalk error "InvalidParameterValueError: No Application Version named 'ap...7' found." Bitbucket pipelines

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

After the command `eb deploy $ENVIRONMENT_NAME` or `eb deploy $ENVIRONMENT_NAME --label` the above error pops up when the same application version is not present in Elastic Beanstalk.

Running this from my local machine (Ubuntu 18.04) creates a new deployment + artifact in S3.

In Bitbucket pipeline, it creates the application artifact but does not deploy it.

```
eb deploy $ENVIRONMENT_NAME --debug
```

Here's the relevant debug log :

```
2020-07-13 03:34:34,990 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Making api call: (elasticbeanstalk, create_application_version) to region: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION with args:{'Process': False, 'ApplicationName': 'build', 'VersionLabel': 'app-d596-200713_033426', 'SourceBundle': {'S3Bucket': 'elasticbeanstalk-$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION-526078354500', 'S3Key': 'build/app-d596-200713_033426.zip'}, 'Description': '--debug'}
2020-07-13 03:34:35,531 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : API call finished, status = 200
2020-07-13 03:34:35,531 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Response: {u'ApplicationVersion': {u'ApplicationName': 'build', u'Status': 'UNPROCESSED', u'VersionLabel': 'app-d596-200713_033426', u'Description': '--debug', u'DateCreated': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 13, 3, 34, 35, 267000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), u'DateUpdated': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 13, 3, 34, 35, 267000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), u'SourceBundle': {u'S3Bucket': 'elasticbeanstalk-$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION-526078354500', u'S3Key': 'build/app-d596-200713_033426.zip'}}, 'ResponseMetadata': {'date': 'Mon, 13 Jul 2020 03:34:35 GMT', 'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': '4dc21b70-15ad-4979-8d7d-2b402a37ebf1'}}
2020-07-13 03:34:35,531 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.elasticbeanstalk : Inside update_env_application_version api wrapper
2020-07-13 03:34:35,531 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Making api call: (elasticbeanstalk, update_environment) to region: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION with args:{'EnvironmentName': '$ENVIRONMENT_NAME', 'VersionLabel': 'app-d596-200713_033426'}
2020-07-13 03:34:36,035 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Response: {'ResponseMetadata': {'date': 'Mon, 13 Jul 2020 03:34:35 GMT', 'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 400, 'RequestId': 'ac898a02-eb2a-4820-aee2-e7f173ee00d8'}, 'Error': {'Message': "No Application Version named 'app-d596-200713_033426' found.", 'Code': 'InvalidParameterValue', 'Type': 'Sender'}}
2020-07-13 03:34:36,035 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : API call finished, status = 400
2020-07-13 03:34:36,035 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Received a 400 Error
2020-07-13 03:34:36,037 (INFO) eb : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/core/ebrun.py", line 62, in run_app
    app.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cement/core/foundation.py", line 797, in run
    return_val = self.controller._dispatch()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cement/core/controller.py", line 472, in _dispatch
    return func()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cement/core/controller.py", line 478, in _dispatch
    return func()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/core/abstractcontroller.py", line 91, in default
    self.do_command()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/controllers/deploy.py", line 78, in do_command
    staged=self.staged, timeout=self.timeout, source=self.source)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/operations/deployops.py", line 75, in deploy
    env_name, app_version_label, group_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/elasticbeanstalk.py", line 681, in update_env_application_version
    VersionLabel=version_label)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/elasticbeanstalk.py", line 39, in _make_api_call
    **operation_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/aws.py", line 221, in make_api_call
    _handle_response_code(e.response, attempt, aggregated_error_message)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/lib/aws.py", line 275, in _handle_response_code
    raise error
InvalidParameterValueError: No Application Version named 'app-d596-200713_033426' found.
```

bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
image: tyrellsys/aws-ebcli

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          script:
            - eb init --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --platform php-5.5
            - eb deploy $ENVIRONMENT_NAME
```

Other similar questions which does not solve this and why :

1. [AWS Elastic Beanstalk ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58513690/aws-elastic-beanstalk-error-invalidparametervalueerror) : No answers
2. [AWS BeanstalkL ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - No Application Version named?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51001505/aws-beanstalkl-error-invalidparametervalueerror-no-application-version-named) : Debug log output is different and the suggestions don't work
3. [Bitbucket Pipelines - No Application Version named found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55313188/bitbucket-pipelines-no-application-version-named-found) : Does not use EB cli

Comment: If you go to the EB console, to Application Versions, does `app-d596-200713_033426` exist?

Comment: No. But app-d596-200713_033426.zip is present in S3.

It works fine from my local machine.

Comment: I have now run to this exactly same issue while trying to make my first deployment to a new application with EB cli. Did you ever find a solution to this 400 error? I also have the correctly named zip file in S3, like you. Doesn't even work from my local machine.

Comment: And right after writing that I discovered that environment names have to be unique ALSO across applications. So you can't have two different applications with same environment name ("develop" or "production" for example)..